# How to render component A from an event handler in component B (function components)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning about hooks via a simple food log app. I have a page with list of buttons (each one is a food). When the user click on a button, that food is showing at the top of the page with the calories eaten. I use two function components: Ate and Food and save both the food list and the ate list in arrays in the localStorage. It works but it requires a page refresh. How do I use hooks to render the Ate component from the onClick event handler in the Food component?

Here is a code sample:

```
const Home = props => {
  const ate = readAte()
  const foods = readFood()

  return (
    <div>
      <Ate ate={ate} />
      <Food food={foods} />
    </div>
  )
}

const getAte = (x, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{x.name}</li>
}

const Ate = props => {
  const { ate } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>I Ate</h2>
      {ate.map(getAte)}
    </div>
  )
}

const getFood = (food, i) => {
  return <FoodItem key={i} data={JSON.stringify(food)} name={food.name} />
}

const Food = props => {
  const { food } = props
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Choose from the list</h2>
      <ul>{food.map(getFood)}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}

const handleFoodClick = event => {
  const ate = JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data'))
  saveAte(ate)
}

const FoodItem = props => {
  const { name, data } = props
  return (
    <li>
      <button onClick={handleFoodClick} data={data}>
        {name}
      </button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/oren/food/blob/fbb2613db93ccecfb04407173e71d525bb7850f4/src/components/tmp.js) is the rest of the code.

Thank you!